# How to convey informally that I acknowledged and I am happy that my advice helped the other person?

Tags: word-request

Acknowledged is a hard long word, every time I say that it's hard and very official. I checked the synonyms like admit, accept, appreciate. But I'm still confused how to tell this in simpler manner.

I have searched these questions

[Usage of "acknowledge"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180132/usage-of-acknowledge)

and some more on stackexchange but I couldn't get any relevant results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An informal way (and perhaps less difficult) to express your acknowledgement and subsequent happiness would be:

- I am **glad to hear** that my advice helped.
- I am **happy to hear** that my advice helped.
- I am **pleased to hear** that my advice helped.

The "**to hear**" expresses your acknowledgement whilst the **glad**/**happy**/**pleased** describes your mood in regards to the acknowledgement, in this case happiness.

Comment: *Glad to hear it* sounds just right. Also, other verbs of understanding like *see*, *learn*, and *know* work.

Comment: Yes, but without the thats.